# Is it possible to split HTML using DOMDocument?

Tags: php, html, domdocument

Using **DOMDocument**, is it possible to split a block of HTML by text wrapped in tags and those that are not, while maintaining the order? Sorry, if this doesn't make sense. My example should make it clear.

Let's say I have the following block of HTML:

```
text1<b style="color:pink">text2</b>text3<b>text4</b> <b style="font-weight:bold">text5</b>
```

Is it possible create an array as such:

```
array(
  [0] => text1 
  [1] => <b style="color:pink">text2</b>
  [2] => text3
  [3] => <b>text4</b>
  [4] => 
  [5] => <b style="font-weight:bold">text5</b>
)
```

Below is my current working solution, which uses a regular expression, to split the HTML.

```
$tokens = preg_split('/(<b\b[^>]*>.*?<\/b>)/i', $html, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

However, I always read that it is a bad idea to parse HTML using regular expressions, so was just wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do it, using the tag name or passing * to get all tags. But if you have a string without properly formatting you can have unexpected results.

For example:

```
$x = 'text1<b style="color:pink">text2</b>text3<b>text4</b> <b style="font-weight:bold">text5</b>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($x);

$array = array ();

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $node)
{
    if ($node->tagName != 'body' && $node->tagName != 'html'){
        $array[] = $dom->saveHTML($node);
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

Would print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <p>text1<b style="color:pink">text2</b>text3<b>text4</b> <b style="font-weight:bold">text5</b></p>
    [1] => <b style="color:pink">text2</b>
    [2] => <b>text4</b>
    [3] => <b style="font-weight:bold">text5</b>
)
```

As you can see, the text outside tags is an attempt of the dom to 'correct' your format, and it can lead to unexpected results.

The reason for `if(.. != 'body' .. . != 'html')` is because the dom puts these tags automatically.

But, if your code is properly formatted, its ok, e.g:

```
$x = '<span>text1</span><b style="color:pink">text2</b><span>text3</span><b>text4</b><b style="font-weight:bold">text5</b>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <span>text1</span>
    [1] => <b style="color:pink">text2</b>
    [2] => <span>text3</span>
    [3] => <b>text4</b>
    [4] => <b style="font-weight:bold">text5</b>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks whomever gave me a comment (and quickly removed it) about looking at the children of the DOMDocument. It helped and allowed me to make a new solution.

```
$tokens = array();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<div>{$html}</div>");
$div = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
if ($div->length) {
    foreach($div->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
        $tokens[] = ($node->nodeName === 'b') ? "<b>{$node->nodeValue}</b>" : $node->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

The only issue is that I can't get the text wrapped in HTML directly without having to build it.